# Aggregating values into previous row based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle19c

I have below input table. I need to create a query to generate the output table which shown below.

The time should be accumulated and the summing up should stop when a record with both time and qty is defined and should restart from there. The Spent_Qty is the sum of all qty defined from both time and qty record till next non zero time and qty record.

**Example:**
first 3 rows has no meaning. 4th row has Qty defined but the next row has time defined so the qty is belong to previous time.
5th row has 3.5 (decimal time) and no Qty so need sum up with next record with qty defined. 6th row has both defined so the sum of time now is 7.25 (time / 60). 6th row has 2 qty defined and 7th row has 0 qty and 0, 8th row has no time but 0.5 qty is show. This should be summed up with 6th row which 2.5. The 9th row has hours defined so need to stop the qty accumulation and restart from here
The result:
7.25hrs took 2.5 spent qty

Example:

**INPUT:**

| Time | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 3.75 | 0 |
| 3.5 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0.5 |
| 2.5 | 0 |
| 2.5 | 0.5 |
| 0 | 0.5 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3.5 | 0.4 |
| 0 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1.75 | 0 |
| 1.75 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0.75 | 1 |

**Output**

| TOT_TIME | Spent QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 7.25 | 2.5 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6.5 | 0.9 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 3.5 | 1 |
| 0.75 | 1 |

I have used LEAD, LAG and other analytical functions. I need to write select statement to get the result along with few other columns. its not working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER     BY rn
  MEASURES
    SUM(time) AS total_time,
    SUM(qty)  AS total_qty
  PATTERN ( ^ no_time* | any_row*? time_and_qty no_time* )
  DEFINE
    time_and_qty AS time > 0 AND qty > 0,
    no_time      AS time = 0
)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| TOTAL_TIME | TOTAL_QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 7.25 | 2.5 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6.5 | .9 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4.25 | 2 |

*Note: The final 4 rows are aggregated together due to the rule "The time should be accumulated and the summing up should stop when a record with both time and qty is defined and should restart from there." It is not until you get to the final row that it has both `time` and `qty`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/72oDCo1d)